# Redactor and html special characters

Tags: javascript, html, redactor

I just set up Redactor wysiwyg. Trying to get autosave working. I have a blank textarea.

`<textarea id='editor1'></textarea>`

Then I have the follow javascript re: Redactor documentation

```
$('#editor1').redactor({
    autosave: "save.php",
    autosaveInterval: 2, // seconds
    autosaveCallback: function(name, json)
    {
        console.log(json.message);
        console.log($('#editor1').redactor('code.get'));
    }
});
```

The save.php file just echos back the data, which is console logged as json.message. The data that gets sent with the autosave is encoded somehow, while the data that I get from just using code.get is not.

This is what gets console logged with a simple `<p>hello</p>`

%253Cp%253E%250A%2509hello%250A%253C%252Fp%253E

I have tried php htmlspecialchars_decode but no change, clearly I am missing something, help?

** EDIT **

Based on the suggestion below, in my php file if you take the data being passed to save.php and use urldecode($data) the %253Cp%253E%250A%2509hello%250A%253C%252Fp%253E is converted to  %3Cp%3E%0A%09asdf%0A%3C%2Fp%3E

If you do urldecode(urldecode( $data ) ) the output becomes `<p>nthellon</p>`

The letters nt and n at the end are the same no matter what text you type between the

tags.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

The % encoding is url encoded.

Comment: When you urldecode the long string above becomes %3Cp%3E%0A%09hello%0A%3C%2Fp%3E

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you urldecode twice it almost works, the tags render correctly but the letters nt are at the beginning of any text that exists between tags.

Comment: I see the same thing in javascript: It seems as though the redactor is encoding an already encoded message.

Comment: Most URL Encoded Strings are % followed by 2 alphanumeric characters, somehow your string actually gets triple encoded...

Comment: Wow, interesting, you're absolutely right. I did urldecode() three times on the data being sent from Redactor and it works.... Not sure that's a solution, but it works. Thanks